# Getting a section of a multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array below. And I am trying to get certain part of the array based on a value that is passed into the function. But for some reason it returns false even though the `path` matches, it only return something if `/test` is used but if I type `/hello` the `if` fails and it returns `false`.

here is the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => test_route
            [path] => /test
            [controller] => TestController
            [action] => indexAction
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => hello_route
            [path] => /hello
            [controller] => HelloController
            [action] => helloAction
        )

)
```

and here is the method:

```
public function getRoute($path = "", $name = "")
{
    foreach($this->routes as $key => $val)
    {
        if($val['path'] === $path || $val['name'] === $name)
        {
            return $this->routes[$key];
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `if` pass or not? Did you check that?

Comment: @Linek it returns false every time. The only time it doesn't is if I send `/test` it finds that one but not the other.

Comment: Are you sure `$this->routes` contains `/hello` path?

Comment: Try to post a minimal example on a site like codepad.org.

Comment: @Linek yes, the multidimensional array above is the result of `print_r($this->routes);`

Comment: It could very well be an html encoding problem. Perhaps you're passing an HTML entity to the function or the array contains an html entity instead. Try echoing out the different variables and make sure you look at the outputted source code so you can see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Since `return false` is inside the `for` loop , only the first element of the array is always checked for . Have a look at my answer , that should correct it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modifying on the code you provided , may be you should try something like this :

```
public function getRoute($path = "", $name = "")
{
    foreach($this->routes as $key => $val)
    {
        if($val['path'] === $path || $val['name'] === $name)
        {
            return $this->routes[$key];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have moved `return false` out side of the `for` loop .

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That definitely looks like the correct answer.

Comment: @Uours thanks that fixed the issue. However although it is not required to use 2 foreach loops do you think it is a good idea? Like in MichaelKings answer? Or would that only be for arrays that are 3 levels deep

Comment: Michael King's answer works for 3 dimensional arrays . Your data array is 2 dimensional and your code is for 2 dimensional array . Considering this already worked for you , I don't see any issue .

Answer (score 0):

Your method exists after examining the first element. Remove the else block and put the return false outside the loop.

```
foreach($this->routes as $key => $val)
    {
        if($val['path'] === $path || $val['name'] === $name)
        {
            return $this->routes[$key];
        }
    }

    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `/test` even works. You're dealing with a multidimensional array. foreach does not do deep searches. You're going to have to modify your code to this:

```
public function getRoute($path = "", $name = "")
{
   foreach($this->routes as $route) { 
        foreach($route as $key => $val)
        {
            if($val['path'] === $path || $val['name'] === $name)
          {
              return $route[$key];
          }

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: the code works without the nested foreach loops. Thanks!